# Try to print the decrease reverse

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an array that prints out the the array as an increase in each inline. But I have trouble doing the reverse as is shown in the below output:

```js
const list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]    //Array

for (let i = 1; i <= list.length; i++) {
  var numStart = '';
  for (let j = 0; j < i; j++) {
    numStart += list[j] +' ';
  }
  console.log(numStart);
}

for (let x = list.length; x <= 4; x--){
    var numStart ='';
    for (let y = x - 1; y < x; y-- ){
        numStart -= list[y] +' ';
    }
    console.log(numStart);
}
```

Expected output

```py
1
1 2 
1 2 3 
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4 5

5 4 3 2 1
5 4 3 2
5 4 3
5 4
5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to start it with `list.length - 1` and go till`x >= 0` and the inner loop should start with the exact value as `x` and go till `y >= 0`

You can use it for decreasing reverse.

```
for (let x = list.length - 1; x >= 0; x--) {
  var numStart = "";
  for (let y = x; y >= 0; y--) {
    numStart += `${list[y]} `;
  }
  console.log(numStart);
}
```

```js
const list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]; //Array

for (let i = 1; i <= list.length; i++) {
  var numStart = "";
  for (let j = 0; j < i; j++) {
    numStart += list[j] + " ";
  }
  console.log(numStart);
}

for (let x = list.length - 1; x >= 0; x--) {
  var numStart = "";
  for (let y = x; y >= 0; y--) {
    numStart += `${list[y]} `;
  }
  console.log(numStart);
}
```